# Is it possible to play the Najdorf Defense if white played 1. d4?

Tags: opening, learning, najdorf

After white plays `1. d4`, is it still possible for black to play the Najdorf Defense?

Is it possible, for Black to play in a way in order to reach a Najdorf setup? If so, how should Black continue?

Comment: Note that opening names refer to the configurations of pieces of both colors, not just one side. You can't play a Najdorf without the cooperation of both players.

Comment: (I wrote more on this common misunderstanding [in response to this question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/a/4259/291)).

Comment: It's possible via transposition, but White must allow it:  1.d4 c5 2.e4 cxd4 3.Nf3 d6 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 a6. Of course, on the second move White could have played 2.d5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If White starts with `1.d4` it is possible to reach a Najdorf position, for example:

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 d6 2.e4 c5 3.Nf3 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6
```

However, White has other moves on move 2, which still give them an advantage: `2. c4` and `2.Nf3`, also White could play `3. c3`. So Najdorf is not that easy to get. Moreover, some people play `1.d4` to avoid Sicilian and especially Najdorf; they will certainly not follow the above line.

Comment: yes that was my question!

Comment: but d4 is a natural move that most people make without thinking, only high rated players know what they do, most people do e4 or d4 naturally

Comment: I checked my database. I have 45,320 Najdorf games, of which only 13 started 1.d4. And then none of those used this move order. 10 times, the games started 1.d4 c5, and then either 2.e4 cxd4 3.Nf3 d6 etc, or 2.Nf3 cxd4 3.Nxd4 Nf6 4.Nc3 d6 5.e4 a6. 3 times, they went 1.d4 Nf6 2.Nc3 c5 3.Nf3 cxd4 4.Nxd4 d6 5.e4 a6. But well, that's one in 3486 Najdorfs that started 1.d4.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, Interesting! Thanks. I checked with an engine and it seems that `2...c5` from black is not very strong and should be met with `3.dxc5` and after `3...Qa5+ 4.Nc3 Qxc5 5. Be3` white has a nice advantage in development. This must be the reason that my given line does not show up.

Comment: That, and there's also 3.d5 with a type of Benoni structure that's usually considered slightly easier to play for white. A 1.d4 player would be much more likely to go for that sort of familiar line than going for an Open Sicilian. That would just giving black what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

If the following five moves by both sides happen in a game, then you have the position that's called the Najdorf Defence:

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 a6
```

However, white is by no means forced to play those moves. He can also play, say, 2.d4, 2.f4, 2.c3, 3.Bb5+, or 4.Qxd4, or 5.f3, or a lot of other moves.

So black can't always get a Najdorf after 1.e4.

Comment: sorry i meant to say d4

Comment: 1.d4 is another way to avoid the Najdorf. A move order like Akavall's is of course possible, but especially 3.Nf3 seems very unlikely to me. It is not realistic to try to get a Najdorf against 1.d4.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 c5 2.e4 cxd4 3.Nf3 d6 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 a6
```

In general, it is not easy to transpose to an "e4" opening when white begins with d2-d4. It is easy for white to avoid the Sicilian system in the example shown above, e.g. with 2.d5 instead of 2.e4. Having said this, some players choose 1.d4 just for fun and would actually prefer to transpose to an "e4" opening if the chance is given. For instance, they would choose 2.e4 in this situation

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 e6 2.e4 d5
```

Thus transposing into the French system. Perhaps because they are scared of the other systems they might face, e.g. 2.c4 f5. So against a player who is not comfortable with the d4-systems, it makes a lot of sense to transpose to your favorite e4-system. Happy hunting!

Comment: Nice answer.  In the first example, I think this is the only reasonable move order that black can try without allowing `dxc5` with a large edge to white.  (`1. d4 d6 2. e4 c5? 3. dxc5! +/-` is just bad for black).

Comment: @Andrew cheers! yes indeed!